# CSS: truetype font not working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am using `font-family` to create code bars, but so far it hasn't been working.
Here is the code:

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: I2of5nt;
    src: url('I2of5nt.ttf');
}
#codeB{
    font-family: I2of5nt;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="codeB">
    1231
</div>
```

Why it doesn't apply the font-type to `<div id="codeB">1231</div>`?

Comment: I suggest including which browsers were giving you trouble.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "I2of5nt";
    src: url('I2of5nt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('FI2of5nt.eot'),
         url('I2of5nt.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('I2of5nt.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('I2of5nt.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Convert the font [here](http://www.font2web.com/) then arrange it in this format. It will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try to add `format('truetype')` like below?

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: I2of5nt;
    src: url('I2of5nt.ttf') format('truetype');
}
#codeB{
    font-family: I2of5nt;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but that didn't work for me. Using Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe caused by wrong font, or your browser does not support TTF format for the font (I don't think so). Try to [convert](http://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff) to **WOFF** and use it instead of TTF.

Example here: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato

TTF/OTF browsers support: http://caniuse.com/ttf