# SCSS: Font not showing up

Tags: css, sass, fonts

**project - src - scss - base - typography.scss:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HankenGrotesk-Bold;
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/HankenGrotesk-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

**project - src - scss - abstracts - variables.scss**

```
$HG-Bold: HankenGrotesk-Bold;
```

(also tried importing the typography.scss file here but didn't change)

**project - src - scss - main.scss**

```
@import "./base/reset.scss";
@import "./base/typography.scss";
@import "./abstracts/mixins.scss";
@import "./abstracts/variables.scss";


h1 {
    font-family: $HG-Bold;
}
```

Live SASS compiler compiles main.min.css into:
**project - src - css - main.min.css**

Import statement in the app that I want to use it for:

```
import "./css/main.min.css";
```

Comment: Are you importing the correct type of font for the browser you are using - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771383/css-truetype-font-not-working.  most modern browsers will use woff2 fonts

Comment: I tried converting it to WOFF and using it. I normally use ttf. Also specified format ('woff'). All of the SCSS and CSS is automatically updated  but I keep getting these random errors:

Comment: ERROR in ./src/css/main.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/main.min.css) 5:36-106

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Instead of

`src: url('../../assets/fonts/HankenGrotesk-Bold.ttf');`

I had to use this

`src: url('.././assets/fonts/HankenGrotesk-Bold.ttf');`

Also, converting to .woff and redoing my links to the main.scss file solved the issue.